# Kotlin compiler pre-release problem in android studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I’m having problems with the project in Android Studio. I get a error message like this

> Class ‘kotlin.Unit’ is compiled by a pre-release version of Kotlin and cannot be loaded by this version of the compiler

almost all of my program code in the project gets the same error message. even though it’s just a simple program code, like this

[image: like this]

Comment: If you're using `1.4-M+` KGP, use the `1.4-rc` version instead

Comment: @mochadwi do you have a link to the version history or something we can refer to when trying to grab the latest release version?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html for stable releases; https://kotlinlang.org/docs/eap.html for EAP @topher217

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add argument`-Xskip-prerelease-check` to IDE.

My solution:

- `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    val kotlin = "1.5.0-M1"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlin
}
tasks{
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions { 
          freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xskip-prerelease-check") 
        }
    }
}
```

- Intellij idea:
  [image]

---

`File -> Invalidate caches / restart -> Invalidate and restart` would not help u.

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem.

You are using pre-release version of kotlin.
Use latest release version of kotlin to solve error.

Right now latest release version is 1.4.31.
Update it on your project gradle file.

ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'

Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the updates from android studio and kotlin to and then 
try File -> Invalidate caches / restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: also make sure to check for `gradle :<main module>:dependencies`: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-compiler-pre-release-problem-in-android-studio-ide/17028/10?u=mochadwi

Answer (score 0):

Please add this task in your `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xskip-prerelease-check"]
        }
    }
```